# Showing Image and User Information on the bottom half of the screen

Tags: java, android

I am working on the android project in which I need to draw a UI something like below. I need to divide the android screen in two half. In the Top Half I need to show the google mps. And in the Bottom Half I need to show the user information as soon as anyone clicked on the `Google Maps`. Top Half part is done and its working for me.

**Problem Statement:-**

I m having trouble in designing the UI for Bottom Half part. What should be the `main.xml file` for the below UI. Whenever I click `markers on the Map`, there `information` should be shown on the bottom half of the Android Screen. Below is the design that I made on the paint
 which contains an image and on the user information in the Bottom Half of the android screen.

[image]

This is what I have currently as a `main.xml file`, which I need to modify to look like above image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" > 

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
        android:id="@+id/mapView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:apiKey="0vAX8Xe9xjo5gkFNEEIH7KdHkNZNJWNnsjUPKkQ" 
        android:clickable="true" 
        android:enabled="true" /> 

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="TextView" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" > 

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
        android:id="@+id/mapView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:apiKey="0vAX8Xe9xjo5gkFNEEIH7KdHkNZNJWNnsjUPKkQ" 
        android:clickable="true" 
        android:state_enabled="true" /> 

    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:baselineAligned="false" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.7" 
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView 
                android:src="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            />

     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textView1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"          
            android:text="Name:" />

       <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textView2" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
            android:text="Gender:" />  

       <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textView3" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
            android:text="Distance:" />        

       <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textView4" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
            android:text="Latitude:" />

       <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textView5" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
            android:text="Longitude:" /> 
    </LinearLayout> 

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Hope that's what you are looking for.